# How do I switch between signatures when modifying a PDF using Preview?

Tags: pdf, preview, signature

I have more than one signature, however when selecting Tools -> Annotate -> Signature, only the most recent signature is inserted.

Is there an option to change the default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, click the Annotations button

[image]

Then click the down arrow on the Signatures button

[image]

You can then select the signature you wish to use.